# Incorrect child querying in solr

Tags: solr, parent-child, nested-documents

Does anyone know what's the problem when solr does not return the correct result when querying child docs? My query is:

```
q = {!parent which="path:2.Project.Submission AND Submission_No:1234"}path:3.Project.Submission.Agency AND Agency_Cd:AGY
```

The expected result is 0 since Submission_No:1234 has a child doc with Agency_Cd:QWE but the solr shows the Submission_No:1234 with child doc Agency_Cd:QWE

Please take note that this parent-child is on the second and third level of the nested documents.

Comment: could you please show sample documents? otherwise a bit difficult to understand your example

Comment: @Mysterion my sample documents can be found here https://pastebin.com/FTR1j6Be, further explanation is that I need to get the document with the path:2.Project.Submission but is filtered by path:3.* and Agency_Cd:AGY